# How to minimize two loss using TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

I am working on a project which is to localize object in a image. The method I am going to adopt is based on the localization algorithm in [CS231n-8](https://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/winter1516_lecture8.pdf).

The network structure has two optimization heads, classification head and regression head. How can I minimize both of them when training the network?

I have one idea that summarizing both of them into one loss. But the problem is classification loss is softmax loss and regression loss is l2 loss, which means they have different range. I don't think this is the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your network status.

If your network is just able to extract features [you're using weights kept from some other net], you can set this weights to be constants and then train separately the two classification heads, since the gradient will not flow trough the constants.

If you're not using weights from a pre-trained model, you

1. Have to train the network to extract features: thus train the network using the classification head and let the gradient flow from the classification head to the first convolutional filter. In this way your network now can classify objects combining the extracted features.
2. Convert to constant tensors the learned weights of the convolutional filters and the classification head and train the regression head.

The regression head will learn to combine the features extracted from the convolutional layer adapting its parameters in order to minimize the L2 loss.

**Tl;dr:**

1. Train the network for classification first.
2. Convert every learned parameter to a constant tensor, using `graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants` as showed in the '[freeze_graph`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py) script.
3. Train the regression head.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer. May I ask one more question that how to represent 'background' class when training regression head? I am using zeros now. Is there a better way?

Comment: You're training the regression head: you don't need the background class. Your train set contains the position of the bounding box of the object, so you'll learn to regress these coordinates and nothing else. The background is everything outside these coordinates.
I use the background class only in the classification head, that's unused while training (I show only images that contain the object) but is used when the network is run in localization mode. If I predict some coordinates with the regression head but the classification head tells me that's background, I skip the location

Comment: That make sense. Thank you.